# $\ell^2$ is a projective limit in the Category of locally convex spaces?

Tags: limits, category-theory, topological-vector-spaces, direct-sum, locally-convex-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^d$ be the usual d-dimensional Hilbert space.  I'm learning about projective limits in the category of LCS with continuous linear maps.

How are the following different; and more importantly for my intuition...what are they each equal to?

- $\projlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$,
- $\projlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}^n$,
- $\oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$?

In each case, the chain maps are the (non-expansive) inclusions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ when $n\leq m$.

My guess is that the first is $\ell^2$ and the second is some sort of tensor algebra but I'm not sure about its topology...

Comment: Are you considering any 'chain maps' $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$? If yes, what? If no, these three would indeed coincide in this category (though I'm not sure they exist, if yes, it's probably $\ell^2$).

Comment: Just the standard inclusion maps as chain maps... I also think $\ell^2$ but I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: Well, the first one would clearly be $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: What you denote as "chain map" is usually denoted as "bonding map". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit.

Comment: Do you really mean $\projlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$? That would be $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You must clarify what you want to know. In the title you write "projective limit" which is also known as "inverse limit", in the text both "direct limit" and "$\projlim$".

Comment: I made the clarification, thanks :)